# writing a filtered list to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, output

I'm trying to create a list from a file based on certain criteria, then filter those items and write them to another file. I have the following, but the new file is empty.

```
def readlinesfromfilecriteria(filename, criteria = ['M','S','T']):
    fd =open(filename)
    lines = fd.readlines()
    filteredlines = []
    fd.close()
    for l in lines:
        if l[0] in criteria:
            filteredlines.append(l)
    return filteredlines
    fd=open('2015PopEstimateSubset.csv','w')
    fd.write(filteredlines.sort)
    fd.close

readlinesfromfilecriteria("2015PopEstimatesComplete.csv")
```

Comment: you're missing parentheses on `close` and `sort`. Check the docs carefully for functions you're using.

Comment: indentation fixed. I'm not receiving any errors, just writing a blank file. If you can't tell, I'm very new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `return` before you start writing anything. Rearrange your code to fix that, most likely you want to move `return` after write. Also `sort()` is not returning anything but sorts in-place, so your `write()` is in vein. You need to either use `sorted()` or sort your list and then write.

Also you should use `with ...` syntax for your file access or add proper error handling.

So you most likely want this:

```
def readlinesfromfilecriteria(filename, criteria = ['M','S','T']):
    with open(filename) as fd:
        lines = fd.readlines()

    filteredlines = [l for l in lines if l[0] in criteria]
    with open('2015PopEstimateSubset.csv','w') as fd:
        fd.write(sorted(filteredlines))

readlinesfromfilecriteria("2015PopEstimatesComplete.csv")
```

Comment: You think his `readlinesfromfilecriteria` function should end in writing to a new file??

Comment: who knows. this is so low quality code that I'd not be surprised. But yes, this is what I think he is having, despite the name. You can screw the indentation while posting, but the order remains unchanged, so for me he is having a function and invocation line. And tons of bugs :)

Comment: Yes, the intent is to end in writing a new file containing only the lines that begin with the criteria. I've fixed the indentation in the post. I know to code is low quality, I'm incredibly new to all of this.

Comment: ha, you see? :)

Comment: but this is terrible. It seems irresponsible to say "No, you're holding it wrong -- here's how you hold a gun when you're shooting yourself in the foot!"

Answer (score -2):

You should call `filteredlines.sort()` and then for line in `filteredlines: fd.write(line)`